# Update Hive metadata location for many tables

Tags: hive, hiveql

I would like to change the bucket name in location of many Hive tables. Is it possible for us to connect to mySQL database and update it? I think it is possible.But I would like to know if it is safe to do it in production database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, and I have seen it done; but

*(a)* the Metastore schema is not documented, and each Hive version brings some minor changes, so you have to do your own **exploration** to find where/how the `StorageDescriptor` objects are persisted -- then some **unit tests / non-regression tests** on a Dev system -- plus, don't forget to run a full **DB backup** before tinkering with your Prod system (and to rehearse an emergency restoration on your Dev system, too!)

*(b)* you have to update the `StorageDescriptor` for tables, but also for **partitions** -- remember that for partitioned tables, the table-level `LOCATION` is just used as default root dir for future partitions; once created, a partition retains its location until it is ALTERed explicitly.

---

For the record, the preferred method for bulk updates is (in theory) the [Hive MetaTool](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+MetaTool) but unfortunately, it does not support the kind of updates that you need.
Right now it's only good for changing the NameNode alias in all HDFS paths, because that was a real [pain point](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3056)...

A valid **alternative** to brutal SQL Updates would be to develop a custom Java program, using the Hive MetaStore API, to scan all tables & partitions then read their StorageDescriptor then run RegEx changes on their Location then write back the changes *(which is exactly what the MetaTool does, only at a lower level)*. But that would be overkill.

---

Finally, a possible **compromise** would be a SQL Select on the appropriate MySQL table, to generate (with `regexp_replace()`) a chain of [ALTER Table/Partition LOCATION](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTable/PartitionLocation) commands to run later in the Hive CLI.
Plus a chain of ALTER to revert to the original locations, in case you have to do an emergency rollback `:-/`